# HuggingFace transformer how to freeze base tranformer after adding additional keras layer

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I want to add a regression layer following the last layer of pretrained BERT model.
So it should be something like:

```
output = bert_model([input_ids,attention_masks])
output = output[1]
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100,activation='relu')(output)
```

But I don't find how I can freeze the BERT model and train only the regression layer.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can freeze the model weights in keras by using `layer_name.trainable = False`

In your case, you can modify as below:

```
# assuming that you have defined bert_model as a layer before
bert_model.trainable = False
output = bert_model([input_ids,attention_masks])
output = output[1]
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100,activation='relu')(output)
```